# Angular Js scope and controller instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to understand my controller and my scope for my angular app.

I used my controller *maincontroller as main* as instance.

Here is what i consoled :-

ang

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main" class="containerWrap ng-scope">
...</div>
```

ang.controller() and ang.scope().main

main is the instance as created above.
Here is a screenshot of both.

The problem that was occurring that I changed i variable before consoling this that is the selfnum as in the screenshot.

Howevere this variable was only changed inside ang.controller() and not ang.scope().main

I wanted to understand what the difference is there between the two.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what is ang ?

Comment: 1. Log `selfnum`, not the whole object. It can make a difference. 2. It's unclear what you have done. Did the change happen within your code? Did you then consecutively log the two objects? 3. You refer to `selfnum` as a variable. Do you actually have a variable `selfnum` or do you mean the property of the controller object? Your question implies the latter.